# python function that iterates over list or, in case of int, just takes int

Tags: python

Is there a more elegant way? I want to let python either iterate over arg, if it is a list, or just take arg, if it is an int. data is a numpy.ndarray

```
def plot(data, run, t):
    if isinstance(run, int):
        run = [run]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    for run in run:
        plt.plot(t, data[run])


    plt.savefig('data.png', dpi=200)
```

Comment: Depends on what you're doing with `arg` in your function. You only want to print?

Comment: I would like to use it as an index in order to access elements of an array

Comment: @Baedsch Can you show a few more lines of code to illustrate that minimally?

Comment: When you created `run` initially, why didn't you always make it a list (with 1 or more elements)? It seems more natural not to mix different data types, and stop the need for this odd fix

Comment: yes, already implemented it, since it is for a framework, it would be sth nice to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce a line in your code:

```
def fcn(arg):
    for a in ([arg] if isinstance(arg, int) else arg):
        print a
```

Comment: looks much better, thx

Answer (score -1):

```
def example(*arg):
  print "I was called with", len(arg), "arguments:", arg

>>> example(1)
I was called with 1 arguments: (1,)
>>> example(1, 2,3)
I was called with 3 arguments: (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I DVed. You're not passing a list in the second case, so this does not address the OP's problem.